# Generate a image with custom text in Android

Tags: java, android, text, bitmap

I'm trying to make an app for create custom cards. I'd like to add some text over a custom background (a jpg image).

What is the best way of doing it? I'd need to show the user a preview of the card before send it to the server.

Thanks

Comment: means you want to add text over an image file ?

Comment: I have an image (.jpg) and want to add the user's text at the top center and generate a new jpg with the text included

Comment: Thanks it is what im looking for

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use below code to achieve your requirement

```
    Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage); // the original file yourimage.jpg i added in resources
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    String yourText = "My custom Text adding to Image";

    Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
    Paint tPaint = new Paint();
    tPaint.setTextSize(35);
    tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    tPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
    float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
    float width = tPaint.measureText(yourText);
    float x_coord = (src.getWidth() - width)/2;
    cs.drawText(yourText, x_coord, height+15f, tPaint); // 15f is to put space between top edge and the text, if you want to change it, you can
    try {
        dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/ImageAfterAddingText.jpg")));
        // dest is Bitmap, if you want to preview the final image, you can display it on screen also before saving
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You have to use below permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For my device the path is `/sdcard` to access external SD card, it may vary for other devices. Some devices may have `/mnt/sdcard` may be it is for internal sd cards. Just check it while before using this code.

Actually I wrote the above code for some other question, which required time stamp on photo after captured from camera. I gave you the same solution with a little modifications for your specific requirement.

I hope you can understand this. If you have any doubts regarding code feel free to ask.

Comment: How can I move the added text on the image using drag and drop.

Comment: Can the same be achieved without saving the image to external storage, just for sending to the server?

Comment: Why is `tPaint.measureText("yY")` supposed to be the height? The documentation of the `measureText` function states that it returns the width of the text.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure this is the best solution, but it might help you.

Step1: Create a relative layout (or any other layout) and set your image as its background.

Step2: Now add a TextView with width and height as `match_parent` and gravity set as `top|center_horizontal`.

Step3: Now add another button or any other layout control which will trigger the user confirmation. (You should place this control outside the Relative layout).

Step4: If user has confirmed the image then you can take screenshot of your relative layout via following code:

```
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //v1 is the object of your Relative layout
            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
            if (bm != null) {

                //TODO: write the code for saving the image.

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "image saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,
                        "No image saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
```