# Add custom text to image and save android

Tags: android, image, performance, bitmap

I am trying to write text on an image and then save it to images.

I have tried
first answer of

[Add text to image in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100428/add-text-to-image-in-android-programmatically)

and

first answer of

[Generate a image with custom text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124896/generate-a-image-with-custom-text-in-android)

I also tried adding text to relative layout, but I could not get it working.

using first two answer I was able to save image to gallery, but the saved images are blurred(no clear).
is there any other technique to save image? or can I improve anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quality of bitmap(image) is maintained specially with this:

```
public boolean compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)
```

here :

**quality** Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting

Comment: thanks, is there any preferred format for max quality?

Comment: http://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/what-is-the-best-image-format-for-android.10016/